# From a list of lists, how do I find lists with n elements in common

Tags: python, list, subset

I have a list of lists

```
foo = [[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12], [1, 2, 5, 17]]
```

I am interested in finding all **possible** groups of lists which share n elements.

**Expected results:**

*Lists sharing 3 elements*

- group containing [1,2,4]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12]]`
- group containing [1,2,17]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 5, 17]]`

*Lists sharing 2 elements*

- group containing [1,2]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12], [1, 2, 5, 17]]`
- group containing [1,4]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12]]`
- group containing [2,4]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12]]`
- group containing [1,17]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 5, 17]]`
- group containing [2,17]: `[[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 5, 17]]`

**What I tried so far**

- Intersection of list: it does not answer my problem as i have no control over the number of elements I'll like my lists to share.

**What I want to try but seems really complicated and they must be a more convenient way**

- For each list, define all combinations of the list minus one element (i.e. subset).
- Loop over the remaining lists and store the ones containing the subset in a dictionary

I posted a minimal example here, but in reality I have a list of hundred of list, each containing 6 elements, so I am afraid of combinatorial explosion as well.

If anyone could offers some guidance or tricks, that will be great.

Many thanks,

Best

Comment: " Intersection of list: it does not answer my problem as i have no control over the number of elements I'll like my lists to share. "
Actually if you find the largest common subset of the two lists, these two lists will share all the combinations of the elements of the largest common subset.
for example list1 and list2 have the intersection of  [1,2,3,4,5]
so they share: [1,2],[1,3]..,[1,5],[2,1],..[4,5],[1,2,3],...,[3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5] 
So you can reduce your problem to find the combinations of the intersection of the two lists. What do you think?

Comment: Are duplicate values possible, like `[1,1,2,3]`?

Comment: @Wups yes, duplicate values are possible

Comment: @Bruck1701 Thanks for your answer, if I understand correctly, you will suggest for each list to calculate the largest subset in common with the remaining list?

Comment: @Bux Did u try out my code?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
from itertools import combinations

def isSubset(comb,lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return all(c in it for c in comb)

foo = [[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12], [1, 2, 5, 17]]
n = 3
print('-'*100)
print(f"n = {n}")
existing = []
for index in range(len(foo)):
    combs = combinations(foo[index],n)
    for comb in combs:
        occurrences = 0
        curr_lst = []
        for lst in foo:
            if isSubset(comb,lst):
                if comb not in existing:
                    occurrences += 1
                    curr_lst.append(lst)
                    if occurrences >= 2:
                        if occurrences == 2:
                            print('-' * 100)
                            print(f"Groups containing {comb}")
                            [print(elem) for elem in curr_lst]
                        else:
                            print(lst)
        existing.append(comb)
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n = 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (1, 2, 4)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 4, 12]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (1, 2, 17)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 5, 17]
```

Output for `n=2`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n = 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (1, 2)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 4, 12]
[1, 2, 5, 17]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (1, 4)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 4, 12]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (1, 17)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 5, 17]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (2, 4)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 4, 12]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Groups containing (2, 17)
[1, 2, 4, 17]
[1, 2, 5, 17]
```

Comment: not downvoter but your code does what the OP doesnt want to " I am afraid of combinatorial explosion as well."

Comment: @python_learner: So you know any better solution? Some problems can't be solved without exponential growth of complexity.

Comment: I did not downvote so I am not sure why you would ask me for a better solution

Comment: not downvoter as well, but I agree that  if the range of the numbers in the inner list is too large, for hundreds of lists, it becomes a problem

Comment: @Sushil this is definitely the closest to what I need so far. I will give it a try and keep you updated.

Comment: `if set(comb).issubset(lst):` would only give the correct result if the values in one sublist are unique, but duplicates are possible.

Comment: @Wups Could u provide an example? So that I can better understand ur point.

Comment: If a sublist is `[1,1,2,3]` a combination could be `[1,1]`, this converted to a set is `{1}`, which gives a wrong result, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @wups yes, absolutely, duplicates values are present and important!

Comment: @Bux I have edited my solution. Try my code with your original list and let me know whether it works. BTW, why did u remove that upvote? Didn't u find my answer helpful? What are the improvements that I should make to my code?

Comment: @Sushil Thanks. However, I did not remove my upvote. I tried your solution, but favored the wups solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way around generating all combinations with n elements for each inner list. But every combination needs to be checked only once:

```
from itertools import combinations
import random

n = 3
foo = [[random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(500)]
#foo = [[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12], [1, 2, 5, 17]]

checked = set() # already checked combinations
result = []

for lst in foo:
    cbs = combinations(lst, n)
    for comb in cbs:
        if not comb in checked:
            groups = [l for l in foo if all(i in l for i in comb)]
            if len(groups) > 1:
                result.append((comb, groups))
            checked.add(comb)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[((1, 2, 4), [[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 4, 12]]),
 ((1, 2, 17), [[1, 2, 4, 17], [1, 2, 5, 17]])]
```

#### Performance:

For the randomly generated list with 500 sublists, values from 0-100 or 0-1000 inside the sublists and `n=2` or `n=3`, the code took a few seconds to complete.

Comment: Thanks @wups, I think this is the closest answer that fits my needs. The performance is also nice (less than a sec for my current data).